# Avoid bad include paths in CMake's pkg-config fallback

Tags: c++, cmake, include-path, pkg-config

One of the canonical ways to include libraries that do not give support for CMake is to fallback to `pkg-config`.

For example the FFTW library can be found in this way:

```
find_package(PkgConfig)

pkg_search_module(FFTW REQUIRED fftw3 IMPORTED_TARGET)
```

and made available by

```
include_directories(PkgConfig::FFTW)
link_libraries(PkgConfig::FFTW)
```

However, in some configurations, `pkg-config` does not return an include path (I guess because if the library headers are in a system path, it is not needed to add an `-I` option).

The problem is that in such a case, CMake attaches the option `-IPkgConfig::FFTW` which is an incorrect path.

In fact the compiler (in my case `g++`) complains, and, with certain warning levels, produces an error.

**How can I prevent CMake or the pkg-config CMake package from generating these bad include paths?**

Comment: Use another canonical (more canonical?) way: write a find module yourself?

Comment: Also if you use `target_link_libraries(target PkgConfig::FFTW)` instead of your global commands you should not have the problem described in the first place. _Maybe_ it should also work with just `link_libraries`, that I'm not sure. What I'm sure about is that you should not have `include_directories(PkgConfig::FFTW)` at all.

Comment: according to the doc you have  `<XXX>_INCLUDE_DIRS` the '-I' preprocessor flags (without the '-I')
ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html#command:pkg_check_modules

Comment: and you have https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake#L313-315 so PkgConfig::FFTW should already have the property `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` correctly set.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44277114/how-to-use-fftw-library-in-cmake

Comment: @ixSci, ok, I use (only) `target_link_libraries(target_name PRIVATE PkgConfig::FFTW)`. I guess the real test will be in a system where pkg-config returns an actual path.