# How do you correctly define the dependencies to FFTW in a cmake file?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, fftw, petsc

I want to use fftw in my c++ program.
For this, I have installed petsc alongside the `--download-fftw` option, since I want to be using Petsc in the future as well. I simply downloaded the most recent stable version, ran `./configure` with the respective options and then `make` -> `sudo make install`

The files are now located in `/usr/local/petsc`, which contain the following fftw files:

```
$ ls /usr/local/petsc/include/
...
fftw3-mpi.f03
fftw3-mpi.h
fftw3.f
fftw3.f03
fftw3.h
fftw3l-mpi.f03
fftw3l.f03
fftw3q.f03
... 

$ ls /usr/local/petsc/lib/
...
libfftw3.a
libfftw3.la
libfftw3.so
libfftw3.so.3
libfftw3.so.3.6.10
libfftw3_mpi.a
libfftw3_mpi.la
libfftw3_mpi.so
libfftw3_mpi.so.3
libfftw3_mpi.so.3.6.10
...
```

I then defined my `CMakeLists.txt` file for my project as following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
add_executable(my_program my_program.cpp)

set(PETSC_DIR "/usr/local/petsc")
target_include_directories(my_program PUBLIC 
                           ${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH} 
                           ${PETSC_DIR}/include)
target_link_libraries(my_program PUBLIC 
                      ${MPI_LIBRARIES} 
                      ${PETSC_DIR}/lib)
```

In `my_program`, I simply call `fftw_mpi_init()`:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <fftw3-mpi.h>
int main(){
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  fftw_mpi_init();
}
```

However, this setup returns the error message

```
undefined reference to `fftw_mpi_init'
```

I realized that `fftw_mpi_init` was not defined anywhere in my `/usr/local/petsc` directory:

[image]

Is this related to my c++ program not being able to find the fftw functions? What steps do I need to take if I want to use the fftw installation that I downloaded alongside petsc?

EDIT: I also tried adding the lines

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(FFTW REQUIRED fftw3 IMPORTED_TARGET)
include_directories(PkgConfig::FFTW)
link_libraries     (PkgConfig::FFTW)
```

to my `CMakeLists.txt` file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44277114/how-to-use-fftw-library-in-cmake/68220409#68220409), but I am still getting the same error `undefined reference to fftw_mpi_init'`.

Comment: This is probably what you want: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/68220409/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68220409/487892)

Comment: @drescherjm thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it didn't work for me, I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to include `${PETSC_DIR}/lib/libfftw3_mpi.a` (the file where `fftw_mpi_init` is defined) and `-lfftw3` in my linker command:

```
...
target_link_libraries(my_program PUBLIC 
                      ${MPI_LIBRARIES} 
                      ${PETSC_DIR}/lib/libfftw3_mpi.a
                      -lfftw3)
...
```