# How to add external library to CMakeLists?

Tags: makefile, cmake, linker, g++, libpqxx

Normal compilation (works fine):

```
g++ DBHandler.cpp Functions.cpp Main.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lconfig++ -lpqxx -lpq -o dbhandler
```

It`s possible to run:

```
./dbhandler
```

CMakeLists.txt (standard):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project(DBHandler)
include_directories(include)
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
target_link_libraries(dbhandler config++ pqxx pq)
add_executable(dbhandler ${SOURCES})
```

How to change CMakeLists.txt and add:

```
-I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lconfig++ -lpqxx -lpq
```

to compile program using cmake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add "-l" (ell) compiler flag in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136418/how-to-add-l-ell-compiler-flag-in-cmake)

Comment: I think you need to create the target first by calling add_executable and later specify the libraries with target_link_libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to use the CMake package `PkgConfig` to use [`pkg_search_module`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPkgConfig.html)

Your file will become:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project(DBHandler)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

pkg_search_module(CONFIGPP REQUIRED config++)
pkg_search_module(PQ REQUIRED pq)
pkg_search_module(PQXX REQUIRED pqxx)

include_directories(include ${CONFIGPP_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PQ_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PQXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
target_link_libraries(dbhandler ${CONFIGPP_LIBRARIES} ${PQ_LIBRARIES} ${PQXX_LIBRARIES})
add_executable(dbhandler ${SOURCES})
```

Comment: CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:637 (message):
  None of the required 'pqxx' found
Libraries were installed by sudo apt-get install ... not from the sources. Maybe, this is the problem of lack findlib.cmake-s files?

Comment: You should install the package `libpqxx-dev` with `sudo apt-get install   libpqxx-dev`