# Dynamic link error cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

When I compile my code using command line everything works fine:

```
g++ main.cpp -lpngwriter
```

But when I try using cmake I get undefined reference errors.
CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(myproject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lpngwriter")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(myproject ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Consider adding `include_directories(/path/to/include)` and `link_directories(/path/to/lib)` before `add_executable()`. And then `target_link_libraries(pngwriter)` after `add_executable()`. Please replace `/path/to` with relevant values.

Comment: Thank you so much, after adding:
include_directories(C:/MinGW/include)
link_directories(C:/MinGW/lib)
and: 
target_link_libraries(myproject pngwriter)
it worked perfectly

Comment: You're always welcome. Shall I repost my advice as an answer?

Comment: Yes, I think that's a good idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add "-l" (ell) compiler flag in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136418/how-to-add-l-ell-compiler-flag-in-cmake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding `include_directories(/path/to/include)` and `link_directories(/path/to/lib)` before `add_executable()`.

And then insert `target_link_libraries(pngwriter)` after `add_executable()`.

`/path/to` shall be replaced with relevant values for your system.