# How to use cmake to compile a C++ shared library project?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a script `compile.sh` which I created based on the Eclipse IDE for my C++ project. Now I am switching to use `cmake` to compile my C++ project. I configured my `cmake` using `ccmake ../`, changed the compiles to use `g++-8` and `gcc`. My `CMakeList.txt` is using `-std=c++17` flag since `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` is not available.

When I use the command `make VERBOSE=1` on the build directory it compiles all my source files, but when it is up to generate the shared library it fails and say it cannot find `pthread_create` and has undefined reference to `gpsmm::stream(int)`. I guess it is because I am not using `$GPP -shared` at the `CMakeList.txt` like I am using at `compile.sh`.

Can anyone help me to compile my shared library using cmake?

Here is my CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(sensors VERSION 0.0.0.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)
#message(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION})


message("---------------------------Release information---------------------------")
message("- Toolchain file: ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}")
message("  - C   Compiler: ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")
message("  - CPP Compiler: ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
message("-------------------------------------------------------------------------")

add_subdirectory(vendor/bcm/)

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
# XXX: this is a little bit ugly but to be done 
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -Wall -fPIC -lpthread -lgps ")

# XXX: a little bit ugly aswell
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/code/*.cpp)

add_library(sensors ${SRC})
target_include_directories(sensors PUBLIC inc)

# XXX: target_link_lib also deals with transitive requirements, the name
#      does not really capture that 
#target_link_libraries(lit ${LIB_X11} ${LIB_FREETYPE} ${LIB_FONTCONFIG} )
# XXX: find out which ones to use PUBLIC and PRIVATE
target_link_libraries(sensors bcm)

add_subdirectory(test)
add_subdirectory(vendor/sense)

#CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug
# set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
```

The error:

```
$ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon -B/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
Re-run cmake file: Makefile older than: ../CMakeLists.txt
---------------------------Release information---------------------------
- Toolchain file: 
  - C   Compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
  - CPP Compiler: /usr/bin/g++-8
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build/CMakeFiles /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build'
make -f vendor/bcm/CMakeFiles/bcm.dir/build.make vendor/bcm/CMakeFiles/bcm.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build'
cd /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/vendor/bcm /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build/vendor/bcm /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build/vendor/bcm/CMakeFiles/bcm.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build'
make -f vendor/bcm/CMakeFiles/bcm.dir/build.make vendor/bcm/CMakeFiles/bcm.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build'
[  6%] Building C object vendor/bcm/CMakeFiles/bcm.dir/src/bcm2835.c.o
cd /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build/vendor/bcm && /usr/bin/gcc   -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/vendor/bcm/include   -o CMakeFiles/bcm.dir/src/bcm2835.c.o   -c /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/vendor/bcm/src/bcm2835.c
[ 13%] Linking C static library libbcm.a
cd /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build/vendor/bcm && /usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/bcm.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build/vendor/bcm && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/bcm.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/ar qc libbcm.a  CMakeFiles/bcm.dir/src/bcm2835.c.o
/usr/bin/ranlib libbcm.a
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build'
[ 13%] Built target bcm
make -f CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build'
cd /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build/CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build'
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/sensor/ISensor.cpp.o
/usr/bin/g++-8    -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/inc -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/vendor/bcm/include  -std=c++17 -Wall -fPIC -lpthread -lgps    -o CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/sensor/ISensor.cpp.o -c /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/code/sensor/ISensor.cpp
[ 26%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/sensor/HCSR04.cpp.o
/usr/bin/g++-8    -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/inc -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/vendor/bcm/include  -std=c++17 -Wall -fPIC -lpthread -lgps    -o CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/sensor/HCSR04.cpp.o -c /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/code/sensor/HCSR04.cpp
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/sensor/Random.cpp.o
/usr/bin/g++-8    -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/inc -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/vendor/bcm/include  -std=c++17 -Wall -fPIC -lpthread -lgps    -o CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/sensor/Random.cpp.o -c /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/code/sensor/Random.cpp
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/sensor/GPS.cpp.o
/usr/bin/g++-8    -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/inc -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/vendor/bcm/include  -std=c++17 -Wall -fPIC -lpthread -lgps    -o CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/sensor/GPS.cpp.o -c /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/code/sensor/GPS.cpp
[ 46%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/CommunicationLib.cpp.o
/usr/bin/g++-8    -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/inc -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/vendor/bcm/include  -std=c++17 -Wall -fPIC -lpthread -lgps    -o CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/CommunicationLib.cpp.o -c /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/code/CommunicationLib.cpp
[ 53%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/utils/LRUBuffer.cpp.o
/usr/bin/g++-8    -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/inc -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/vendor/bcm/include  -std=c++17 -Wall -fPIC -lpthread -lgps    -o CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/utils/LRUBuffer.cpp.o -c /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/code/utils/LRUBuffer.cpp
[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/utils/Metric.cpp.o
/usr/bin/g++-8    -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/inc -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/vendor/bcm/include  -std=c++17 -Wall -fPIC -lpthread -lgps    -o CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/utils/Metric.cpp.o -c /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/code/utils/Metric.cpp
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/utils/SkinnyBuffer.cpp.o
/usr/bin/g++-8    -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/inc -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/vendor/bcm/include  -std=c++17 -Wall -fPIC -lpthread -lgps    -o CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/utils/SkinnyBuffer.cpp.o -c /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/code/utils/SkinnyBuffer.cpp
[ 73%] Linking CXX static library libsensors.a
/usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/ar qc libsensors.a  CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/sensor/ISensor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/sensor/HCSR04.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/sensor/Random.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/sensor/GPS.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/CommunicationLib.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/utils/LRUBuffer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/utils/Metric.cpp.o CMakeFiles/sensors.dir/code/utils/SkinnyBuffer.cpp.o
/usr/bin/ranlib libsensors.a
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build'
[ 73%] Built target sensors
make -f test/CMakeFiles/sensorTests.dir/build.make test/CMakeFiles/sensorTests.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build'
cd /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/test /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build/test /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build/test/CMakeFiles/sensorTests.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build'
make -f test/CMakeFiles/sensorTests.dir/build.make test/CMakeFiles/sensorTests.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build'
[ 80%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/sensorTests.dir/main.cpp.o
cd /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build/test && /usr/bin/g++-8    -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/test/include -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/inc -I/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/vendor/bcm/include  -std=c++17 -Wall -fPIC -lpthread -lgps    -o CMakeFiles/sensorTests.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/test/main.cpp
[ 86%] Linking CXX executable sensorTests
cd /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build/test && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/sensorTests.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/g++-8    -std=c++17 -Wall -fPIC -lpthread -lgps    CMakeFiles/sensorTests.dir/main.cpp.o  -o sensorTests  -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6 ../libsensors.a ../vendor/bcm/libbcm.a 
../libsensors.a(GPS.cpp.o): In function `GPS::run()':
GPS.cpp:(.text+0x973): undefined reference to `gpsmm::stream(int)'
GPS.cpp:(.text+0x9cb): undefined reference to `gpsmm::waiting(int)'
GPS.cpp:(.text+0x9e5): undefined reference to `gpsmm::read()'
GPS.cpp:(.text+0xa2a): undefined reference to `gpsmm::read()'
GPS.cpp:(.text+0xc31): undefined reference to `gpsmm::~gpsmm()'
GPS.cpp:(.text+0xc56): undefined reference to `gpsmm::~gpsmm()'
../libsensors.a(GPS.cpp.o): In function `std::thread::thread<GPS::connect()::{lambda()#1}>(GPS::connect()::{lambda()#1}&&)':
GPS.cpp:(.text+0xdad): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
../libsensors.a(GPS.cpp.o): In function `gpsmm::gpsmm(char const*, char const*)':
GPS.cpp:(.text._ZN5gpsmmC2EPKcS1_[_ZN5gpsmmC5EPKcS1_]+0x17): undefined reference to `vtable for gpsmm'
GPS.cpp:(.text._ZN5gpsmmC2EPKcS1_[_ZN5gpsmmC5EPKcS1_]+0x5f): undefined reference to `gpsmm::gps_inner_open(char const*, char const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
test/CMakeFiles/sensorTests.dir/build.make:96: recipe for target 'test/sensorTests' failed
make[2]: *** [test/sensorTests] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:178: recipe for target 'test/CMakeFiles/sensorTests.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/sensorTests.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/build'
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

and how I used to compile using `compile.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

#set -e 
GPP="g++-8"
CPP="-std=c++17"
GCC="gcc"


# This is a neater way to do so (then you do not have to append each file on
# your own
echo "Cleaning code from binaries and shared library"
touch i.o
rm $(find -name '*.o') $(find -name '*.d') $(find -name '*.so')


echo "compiling the shared library on different machines"
$GPP $CPP -I"ide/CommunicationLib/../../inc" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -pthread -MMD -MP -MF"code/utils/LRUBuffer.d" -MT"code/utils/LRUBuffer.o" -o "code/utils/LRUBuffer.o" "code/utils/LRUBuffer.cpp"
$GPP $CPP -I"ide/CommunicationLib/../../inc" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -pthread -MMD -MP -MF"code/utils/Metric.d" -MT"code/utils/Metric.o" -o "code/utils/Metric.o" "code/utils/Metric.cpp"
$GPP $CPP -I"ide/CommunicationLib/../../inc" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -pthread -MMD -MP -MF"code/utils/SkinnyBuffer.d" -MT"code/utils/SkinnyBuffer.o" -o "code/utils/SkinnyBuffer.o" "code/utils/SkinnyBuffer.cpp"
$GPP $CPP -I"ide/CommunicationLib/../../inc" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -pthread -MMD -MP -MF"code/sensor/GPS.d" -MT"code/sensor/GPS.o" -o "code/sensor/GPS.o" "code/sensor/GPS.cpp"
$GPP $CPP -Ivendor/bcm/include/ -I"ide/CommunicationLib/../../inc" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -pthread -MMD -MP -MF"code/sensor/HCSR04.d" -MT"code/sensor/HCSR04.o" -o "code/sensor/HCSR04.o" "code/sensor/HCSR04.cpp"
$GPP $CPP -I"ide/CommunicationLib/../../inc" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -pthread -MMD -MP -MF"code/sensor/ISensor.d" -MT"code/sensor/ISensor.o" -o "code/sensor/ISensor.o" "code/sensor/ISensor.cpp"
$GCC -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -Ivendor/bcm/include/ -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"vendor/bcm/src/bcm2835.d" -MT"vendor/bcm/src/bcm2835.o" -o "vendor/bcm/src/bcm2835.o" "vendor/bcm/src/bcm2835.c" 
$GPP $CPP -I"ide/CommunicationLib/../../inc" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -pthread -MMD -MP -MF"code/CommunicationLib.d" -MT"code/CommunicationLib.o" -o "code/CommunicationLib.o" "code/CommunicationLib.cpp"
$GPP -shared -o "./lib/libCommunicationLib.so"  ./code/utils/LRUBuffer.o ./code/utils/Metric.o  ./code/utils/SkinnyBuffer.o ./code/sensor/GPS.o ./code/sensor/HCSR04.o ./code/sensor/ISensor.o  ./vendor/bcm/src/bcm2835.o  ./code/CommunicationLib.o   -lpthread -lgps

echo "cleaning headers and sources from the test project"
rm -rf  ./test/main.o  ./test/main.d  TestCommunicationLib.so

echo "compiling the test project which uses the shared library on different machines"
$GPP $CPP -I"ide/TestCommunicationLib/../../inc" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"test/main.d" -MT"test/main.o" -o "test/main.o" "test/main.cpp"
$GPP $CPP -L"ide/TestCommunicationLib/../../lib" -o "TestCommunicationLib.so"  ./test/main.o   -lCommunicationLib

# configure lib directory
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: I think its the ordering in the link command. In your script -lgps is right at the end; in the cmake output it comes too early. I'm no expert on cmake but adding gps to `target_link_libraries` may help

Comment: @virgesmith thanks! I add pthread and gps at `target_link_libraries` and it worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add "-l" (ell) compiler flag in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136418/how-to-add-l-ell-compiler-flag-in-cmake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `target_link_libraries(sensors bcm pthread gps)` to the `CMakeList.txt` like @virgesmith mentioned on the comments and it worked.