# Converting a Makefile into CMakeLists.txt equivalent

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I am working on a project were I maintain a CMakeLists.txt file to keep track of the dependencies when I need to compile.

I recently, started using a new library that I need to integrate in my project. The library comes with some examples on how to compile but this is purely a Makefile. I would like to integrate the logic of the Makefile into my project's CMakeLists.txt file.

The Makefile of this library is as follows:

```
COMMON=-O2 -I/home/john/.mujoco/mjpro200/include -L/home/john/.mujoco/mjpro200/bin -std=c++11 -mavx -pthread -Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN'

all:
    g++ $(COMMON) basic.cpp      -lmujoco200 -lGL -lglew /home/john/.mujoco/mjpro200/bin/libglfw.so.3 -o basic
    gcc -c -O2 -mavx -I/home/john/.mujoco/mjpro200/include /home/john/.mujoco/mjpro200/include/uitools.c
    rm *.o
```

I would like to convert this Makefile into CMakeLists.txt exactly if possible. I see that they provide some flags for threading (`pthread`) and I want to keep these flags and settings in my CMakeLists.txt in case they are needed for performance.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6.0)
project(myproject)
add_compile_options(-std=c++11) # CMake 2.8.12 or newer

if( CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC OR CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX )
  add_definitions("-fno-strict-aliasing -Wall")
endif( CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC OR CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX )

# optional in case boost is used
find_package(Boost 1.58 EXACT)
find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)

set(mujocoCommon "-O2 -I/home/john/.mujoco/mjpro200/include -L/home/john/.mujoco/mjpro200/bin -std=c++11 -mavx -pthread -Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN'")

set(Mujoco_INCLUDE_DIRS "/home/john/.mujoco/mjpro200/include")

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Mujoco_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_executable(myproject mycode.cpp)
install(TARGETS myproject DESTINATION .)
```

So I tried to define a variable `mujocoCommon` similar to the `COMMON` in the Makefile as well as the `Mujoco_INCLUDE_DIRS` that I then use in the CMake's `include_directories`.

Note that in the `myproject.cpp` I have MuJoCo code and other dependencies that I need to correctly link against. In the Makefile things looks a bit more simpler because in there the code has only MuJoco dependencies.

I need some heads-up on how to add in my CMakeLists.txt the following:

- `-mavx -pthread -Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN'` part of Makefile's COMMON variable.
- `-lmujoco200 -lGL -lglew /home/john/.mujoco/mjpro200/bin/libglfw.so.3`
- `-c -O2 -mavx -I/home/john/.mujoco/mjpro200/include /home/john/.mujoco/mjpro200/include/uitools.c`

Currently with the minimal knowledge on CMake and what I have in my CMakeLists.txt when I compile using "make" I get many errors of the kind:

```
myproject.cpp:(.text+0xfa9): undefined reference to `glfwSetMouseButtonCallback'
```

Basically I would like to link (?) my code with MuJoco library as is done in their Makefile.

Thanks.

**Edit**
In regards with the possible duplicate flag, I added the following flag:

```
set(Mujoco_LIBRARIES "/home/john/.mujoco/mjpro200/bin")
target_link_libraries(myproject ${Mujoco_LIBRARIES} -lboost_system)
```

But it didn't solved the problem.

**Edit 2:**

I have also added this one:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lmujoco200 -lGL -lglew /home/john/.mujoco/mjpro200/bin/libglfw.so.3")
```

The errors I am getting:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lmujoco200
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lglew
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add "-l" (ell) compiler flag in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136418/how-to-add-l-ell-compiler-flag-in-cmake)

Comment: Your makefile has `-lgl` and `-lglew` flags. I see neither of them (and their equivalent) in your `CMakeLists.txt`. (Suggestion: Split your task for converting Makefile into **smaller tasks**. Then google/search for information about every small task. If you cannot resolve some small task, then ask on Stack Overflow about this specific task.)

Comment: Also see [CMake link to external library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8774593/608639). I believe it covers the case of building a library using a Makefile, and then importing it into your project.

Comment: Also, if you are setting an RPATH with `-Wl,-rpath,<path>`, then you often want to use `-Wl,--enable-new-dtags` on newer systems with ELF binaries.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add the opengl libraries to the link libraries, `target_link_libraries`. Don't add them with `-l`.