# How to set g++ compile options in CLion?

Tags: cmake, clion

My code runs correctly in the terminal when I compile it like

```
g++ -g -O2 -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib main.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -fopenmp -lpthread -o main -lz
```

But when I run it from CLion it gives a bunch of errors specifically linking

```
Undefined reference to gzread/gzclose/gzopen
```

which I believe is due to not specifying the compile options while compiling.

How do I set the compile options in CLion?

**EDIT**

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Partition)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(Partition main.cpp kseq.h)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++1y -O2 -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -fopenmp -lpthread -lz")
```

Comment: `target_link_libraries` in CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Yes but I don't know how exactly to write it. Do I write like this target_link_libraries (-g -O2 -std=c++11 etc)?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-cmake-tutorial.html

Comment: @arved I have already gone through the link. I can't make it work though. CLion throws same linking error.

Comment: Then post your CMakeList.txt

Comment: Please see the Edit.

Comment: @Harsh SO is a Question and Answer platform, so do not update your question to include the Solution. if you think that the given answer(s) are missing a necessary detail to full answer your question then create your own answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add "-l" (ell) compiler flag in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136418/how-to-add-l-ell-compiler-flag-in-cmake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the compiling step that is failing but the linking step.

The `-l` parts of your command line string are the linking options, and list the libraries to which you want to link your program to.

The names that at listed after each of these `-l` have to be added using the `target_link_libraries(Partition boost_system ...)`

Comment: Did this : target_link_libraries(-lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lpthread -lz). Which gave this error : CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "-lboost_system" which is not
  built by this project.