# Using yacc(1) with CMake on OpenBSD

Tags: c, makefile, build, cmake, openbsd

I want to set up a development environment for [httpd(8)](https://github.com/reyk/httpd) on OpenBSD with CLion (I'm using the [Remote Project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/remote-projects-support.html) feature of CLion, but this isn't very different from working at an OpenBSD box). However, CLion forces me to use CMake, and I'm having some problem porting the `Makefile` into a `CMakeLists.txt`.

This is the `Makefile` from the original repo

```
#   $OpenBSD: Makefile,v 1.30 2017/07/03 22:21:47 espie Exp $

PROG=       httpd
SRCS=       parse.y
SRCS+=      config.c control.c httpd.c log.c logger.c proc.c
SRCS+=      server.c server_http.c server_file.c server_fcgi.c
MAN=        httpd.8 httpd.conf.5

SRCS+=      patterns.c
MAN+=       patterns.7

LDADD=      -levent -ltls -lssl -lcrypto -lutil
DPADD=      ${LIBEVENT} ${LIBTLS} ${LIBSSL} ${LIBCRYPTO} ${LIBUTIL}
#DEBUG=     -g -DDEBUG=3 -O0
CFLAGS+=    -Wall -I${.CURDIR}
CFLAGS+=    -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes
CFLAGS+=    -Wmissing-declarations
CFLAGS+=    -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith
CFLAGS+=    -Wsign-compare -Wcast-qual
YFLAGS=

.include <bsd.prog.mk>
```

Despite the arcane syntax, it works perfectly on OpenBSD, and here is the output

```
openbsd$ uname -a
OpenBSD openbsd.my.domain 6.4 GENERIC#10 amd64
openbsd$ make
===> httpd
yacc  -o parse.c parse.y
cc -O2 -pipe  -Wall -I/home/nalzok/httpd/httpd -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-compare -Wcast-qual  -MD -MP  -c parse.c
cc -O2 -pipe  -Wall -I/home/nalzok/httpd/httpd -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-compare -Wcast-qual  -MD -MP  -c config.c
cc -O2 -pipe  -Wall -I/home/nalzok/httpd/httpd -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-compare -Wcast-qual  -MD -MP  -c control.c
cc -O2 -pipe  -Wall -I/home/nalzok/httpd/httpd -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-compare -Wcast-qual  -MD -MP  -c httpd.c
cc -O2 -pipe  -Wall -I/home/nalzok/httpd/httpd -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-compare -Wcast-qual  -MD -MP  -c log.c
cc -O2 -pipe  -Wall -I/home/nalzok/httpd/httpd -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-compare -Wcast-qual  -MD -MP  -c logger.c
cc -O2 -pipe  -Wall -I/home/nalzok/httpd/httpd -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-compare -Wcast-qual  -MD -MP  -c proc.c
cc -O2 -pipe  -Wall -I/home/nalzok/httpd/httpd -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-compare -Wcast-qual  -MD -MP  -c server.c
cc -O2 -pipe  -Wall -I/home/nalzok/httpd/httpd -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-compare -Wcast-qual  -MD -MP  -c server_http.c
cc -O2 -pipe  -Wall -I/home/nalzok/httpd/httpd -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-compare -Wcast-qual  -MD -MP  -c server_file.c
cc -O2 -pipe  -Wall -I/home/nalzok/httpd/httpd -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-compare -Wcast-qual  -MD -MP  -c server_fcgi.c
cc -O2 -pipe  -Wall -I/home/nalzok/httpd/httpd -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-compare -Wcast-qual  -MD -MP  -c patterns.c
cc   -o httpd parse.o config.o control.o httpd.o log.o logger.o proc.o server.o server_http.o server_file.o server_fcgi.o patterns.o -levent -ltls -lssl -lcrypto -lutil
```

As [@Tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/98357500) wisely pointed out in a comment, I must build `parse.c` from `parse.y` before linking everything together to produce an executable. Among others, `bison(1)` is a popular tool for making `*.c` from `*.y`, so my attempt looks like this. You must also install `bison(1)` and pass `-DBISON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/bison` to CMake.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(httpd)

find_package(BISON REQUIRED)
bison_target(parse httpd/parse.y "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parse.c")

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS
        "-Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes"
        "-Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith"
        "-Wsign-compare -Wcast-qual")

add_executable(httpd
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parse.c"
        httpd/config.c httpd/control.c httpd/httpd.c httpd/log.c httpd/logger.c httpd/proc.c
        httpd/server.c httpd/server_http.c httpd/server_file.c httpd/server_fcgi.c
        httpd/patterns.c)
target_link_libraries(httpd event tls ssl crypto util)
```

This problem is, CMake only provides a [FindBISON module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBISON.html) for `bison(1)`, but what I really need to call is OpenBSD's stock [`yacc(1)`](http://man.openbsd.org/yacc). Note that these two utilities are not perfectly interchangeable. For example, the `yacc` doesn't support the `--version` flag, whereas `bison` does. How do I instruct CMake to use `yacc`?

As a side note, this project is only intended to be deployed on OpenBSD, so feel free to use any unportable hack.

Comment: It seems that `main` function in your case is defined in the `parser.y` file, which should be processed by Bison before passing it to compiler. Passing this file directly to `add_executable` doesn't work as you think. See duplicate question (and answer for it) about proper working with such files in CMake. Also, speciying `-l` options in `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` variable is wrong. See that question for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43136418/3440745.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the links, but I'm afraid this is not a duplicate. OpenBSD processes `*.y` files with [yacc(1)](http://man.openbsd.org/yacc) instead of `bison`, so I cannot simply use `find_package(BISON REQUIRED)`.

Comment: As far as I undestand, `bison` and `yacc` programs are very internchangable. If `find_package(Bison)` doesn't work for you *out-of-the-box*, pass option `-DBISON_EXECUTABLE=yacc` to `cmake`. In any case, your question should describe that `main` function is defined in `parser.y`. "Guess-what-my-project-does" is not the way how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Didn't realize I can specify the executable to cmake! The stock `yacc(1)` doesn't support the `--version` argument which cmake uses, so I ended up installing GNU bison and passing `-DBISON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/bison`. Maybe this trick will work, but the `--version` issue clearly suggests these two are incompatible in some ways. Also, I don't think it's reasonable to expect me to realize `main` resides in `parser.y`. I'm cloning the repo from GitHub to study, and I haven't seen any `*.y` files before.

Comment: Hm, so `yacc` and `bison` are not so interchangable. If you want your question to ask about using explicitely `yacc` in CMake, then rephrase the question, and I will reopen it. "Also, I don't think it's reasonable to expect me to realize `main` resides in `parser.y`." - You want to port the project, so you need to understand that project. At least, when face the error about missed `main`, you should be able to search its definition. Unlike to you, we cannot perform that search because we don't have the project's sources.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Please take a look at my edited question, and reopen it if you see fit.

Comment: Ok, the question becomes clear and does not fit to the duplicate. So I have reopened it.

Comment: Note, that setting `BISON_EXECUTABLE` is needed only when the executable is not default one (e.g. you want to use `yacc` instead of `bison`, or wont to use bison which is installed locally). Normally, CMake is able to find that executable by itself, without hints.

Comment: `bison` has a special switch to emulate yacc: `bison -y`.